# Create seamless tileable images

Tags: images, image-processing, 3d

What software can create a seamless tileable image from a resource image?

I am familiar with the techniques in Photoshop, but I am more interested in software applications that are dedicated to this purpose and are more fully automated and flexible.

Tileable images are important for texturing 3D computer models and graphics.

Comment: Some ideas: http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=31854